# SUM() in SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Simple question really but it seems tricky to do:

I am trying to convert the following SQL Query to LINQ expression:

```
select SUM(timespan) as timespan from TimeRegistrations as tr 
where Activity_Id_FK =1 and tr.date>= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE());
```

This is what I have so far :

```
var total_hours_spent = from e in DB.TimeRegistrations 
where e.Activity_Id_FK ==activity_id && e.date >=date.AddDays(30)
select e.Sum(e.timespan);
```

The compiler complains at e.Sum(e.timespan). I don't know how to select the Sum of the timespan from the TimeRegistrations table. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query `e` is a single `TimeRegistration` entity with its Activity_Id_FK, date and other fields. So, you problem is here:

```
e.Sum(e.timespan)
```

Here you have two issues - first one is calling `Sum` on entity (it's not queryable set of entities - there is nothing to sum in single entity). And you missed syntax of `Sum` method - it should accept lambda with property selector `Sum(e => e.timespan)`.

You should select `timespan` values from `TimeRegistrations` table, and then call `Sum()` method:

```
(from e in DB.TimeRegistrations 
 where e.Activity_Id_FK ==activity_id && e.date >= date.AddDays(30)
 select e.timespan).Sum()
```

SQL query will be generated only when `Sum()` is called, so it will end up with query you want. You also can select whole `TimeRegistrations` entity and then select which field to sum (same query will be generated):

```
(from e in DB.TimeRegistrations 
 where e.Activity_Id_FK ==activity_id && e.date >= date.AddDays(30)
 select e).Sum(e => e.timespan)
```

I don't like to mix query syntax with method calls, so here is pure lambda syntax:

```
DB.TimeRegistrations
  .Where(e => e.Activity_Id_FK == activity_id && e.date >= date.AddDays(30))
  .Sum(e => e.timespan)
```

BTW: Small advise - choose variable names which correlate with entity they represent. E.g. instead of `e` I'do go with variable `r` or `tr` to represent TimeRegistration entity.

Comment: I assume some explanation is coming as well as the code?

Comment: @JonSkeet just as you always do)

Comment: Thanks that was fast... it didnt come to my mind!! Thanks again!

Comment: Watch out for the difference in Sum semantics between SQL and linqtosql. If no rows are found you will get an exception if timespan is a non-nullable. use a nullable type `e => (TimeSpan?)e.timespan`

Answer (score 0):

Apply sum after query like this one,

```
var total_hours_spent = (from e in DB.TimeRegistrations 
where e.Activity_Id_FK ==activity_id && e.date >=date.AddDays(30)
select e).Sum(e => e.timespan);
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: Is there something new in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to find total hours spent

```
var total_hours_spent = (from e in DB.TimeRegistrations 
    where e.Activity_Id_FK ==activity_id && e.date >=date.AddDays(30)
    select e).Sum(e => e.timespan.TotalHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more readable syntax

```
var total_hours_spent = DB.TimeRegistrations
                          .Where(e => e.Activity_Id_FK ==activity_id && 
                                      e.date >=date.AddDays(30))
                          .Sum(e => e.timespan);
```